# Select from nothing in Oracle without referencing the dual table?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

selecting from nothing in Oracle SQL happens while referencing the dual table, like

```
SELECT sysdate FROM dual;
```

Now I'd like to have a query that also works for PostgreSQL, but selecting from dual there isn't possible. I know that I can drop the whole `FROM` part, but then it won't work in Oracle.

I've also tried things like `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM VALUES(1)) V(C);`, but Oracle can't do this, either.

**So is there a way to select from nowhere without using the `dual` table in Oracle SQL?**

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: I am not familiar with PostgreSQL, but (using concepts from Oracle) it seems it should be possible to create a **view** called `DUAL` in Postgre - something like `create view DUAL as select 'X' as DUMMY` (no need to add `... from <whatever>`, as I understand it). Then selecting from `DUAL` in Postgre should work exactly the same as in Oracle.

Comment: Mind that `SELECT` without a table is not standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, create a table named `dual` in Postgres, made of 1 row and 1 column

```
create table dual as (select 1);
```

and you can use it in Postgres as you would in Oracle

```
select 'whatever' from dual;
 ?column?
-----------
 whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

`sysdate` in Oracle is a built-in function, i.e. not a database table column. You can use any table as long as the query returns precisely one row, e.g.

```
select sysdate from EMP where rownum < 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a small table, TABLE_B, with at least one row, you could try selecting a single row from it.

```
select sysdate from TABLE_B where rownum < 2;
```

The contents of the table don't matter because you won't be selecting any of its columns.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 21c and below, the below code generates a fake row in both Oracle and Postgres (10+), using the `XMLTABLE` function.  This code is pretty weird but it doesn't require any custom objects.

```
--Generate a fake row in either Oracle or Postgres.
select *
from xmltable
(
    --The expression syntax is different for Oracle and Postgres.
    --Oracle can use a literal, Postgres must reference the XML.
    --The string '' is null in Oracle but not null in Postgres.
    case when '' is null then '1' else '/a' end passing '<a>1</a>'
    columns test int path '.'
);

test
----
   1
```

---

In Oracle 23c and above, Oracle finally supports selecting without a `FROM` clause:

```
SQL> select sysdate;

SYSDATE
---------
06-APR-23
```