# String Aggregation that works in both oracle and postgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I was originally using `LISTAGG` to do the union of strings in oracle.

Searching for PostgreSQL I get: `string_agg`

I don't know if there is any way to have a function that works in both applications.

I have to do it from the query since I can't create functions

thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you need to use exact SQL in two different applications with different rdms? You can maybe add some oracle -> postgres conversion logic in second app? Or simple string replace?

Comment: Generally, standard SQL functions are common across various RDBMSes. However, it is not reasonable to expect a common function to be there for all operations across database products. You have to ideally use separate code-bases for Oracle and Postgres using functions and operators relevant to those DBs.

Comment: While you could easily write a `listagg()` function in Postgres, I am not sure if you can write it in such a way that it also accepts the `WITHIN GROUP` part that Oracle requires. I _think_ it's possible, but probably not easy

Comment: @buræquete 
Well, it is an application that will be used in both databases, different companies and we were trying to make as synchronized as possible

Comment: @KaushikNayak 
That was our first option, but we want to see if there was any possibility

Comment: @Maverick2786 I bet there's a way to make this work in both databases using XML functions, like `XMLAGG`.  The XML functionality is relatively similar between the two databases, and I was able to use a related hack in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54845362/409172), which shows how to use empty strings to determine the database engine being used.  Unfortunately I can't get `XMLAGG` to work here, but hopefully someone else can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help, in the end I did it through functions and sub-query